# Three.js keyframe animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, keyframe

this is my first post and I need an answer I didn't find anywhere else. Oh and btw I am not a professional programmer, actually more like a 3d graphic designer ;)
I would like to import json models with a simple animations ( just translation e rotation ) made in 3ds max.
I just found examples about skinned meshes and bone animations, but that's far from what I want.

I simply need three.js to load and play a keyframe animation when I press a button. Can someone help me find a solution?

Thanks everybody in advance, Andrea.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this example [Import Collada to THREEJS](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_collada_keyframe)  
Press "View Source" and look at model path and Animations script usage.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I will take a look at Collada importer. Is Collada a special file format or just an importer for json models which support animation keyframe?

Comment: Collada it is file format. When you export from 3D Max to Collada you can include all scene ( camera, lights, models ). Then using ThreeJS Collada importer you can load this full scene to the web.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to replicate the animation using [Tween.JS](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/), which is a library that [is used in one of Three.js examples](https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_cubes_tween).

If you're interested using this technique, there is also [an in-depth tutorial](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/) combining the two.

Comment: Hi Pim, thanks for the answer. I already used Tween but in this case I wanted to import pre animated objects. The reason is that the HTML page must be loaded from a DB and the meshes are loaded dinamically too. This means it would be more complex to apply the right tween animation to the right mesh I guess.