# ThreeJS building Animation

Tags: animation, three.js

I am trying to create an effect similar to this, https://aframe.io/. Where the object builds itself when the page loads. I have tried searching through the code and can't find how to animate it.

I found a few pieces of code similar to this,

```
<a-entity rotation="-20 0 0" position="0 0 10.75" scale="1 0 1">
<a-animation attribute="scale" to="1 1 1" delay="200" dur="1000" easing="ease-out"></a-animation>
<a-box width="12.5" depth="1" height="30" color="#EF2D5E" position="0 15 0">
```

`easing="ease-out"` would be the only thing I can see relating to that effect.

Comment: Are you using A-Frame, or purely three.js? If you're not using A-Frame, I don't think its source code will help much here.

Comment: Three.js, any suggestions?

Comment: There are some good suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664406/three-js-keyframe-animation